# updating cookies with jquery

Tags: asp.net, jquery, cookies

I'm trying to implement a side menu that saves it previous state (or selected item) after a submit or after the user refreshes the page.

I decided to use cookies to save the index of the selected item of the menu.

However, is not working everytime. What's going on?

Here's my code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            var cookie = $.cookie("SelectedNode");

            $('.t-link').click(function () {
                        var name = "SelectedNode";
                        var index = getIndex($(this));
                        $.cookie(name, null);   //delete previous value
                        $.cookie(name, index);
                        alert("It should save: " + index + " but it saved: " + $.cookie("SelectedNode"));
            });
});
```

Comment: I'd recommend not using cookies for this. You're just increasing the HTTP overhead with every request to the server.

Comment: what do you recommend me to do then?

Answer (score 0):

I would go like this, I don't think you need to delete the cookie value, it just overrides the existing one.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            var name = "SelectedNode";
            $('.t-link').click(function () {
                        var cookie = $.cookie(name, getIndex($(this)));
            });
});
```

Comment: It does the same thing... it overrides the existing one sometimes sometime it doesn't update the value...

Answer (score 0):

Updating the same cookie with constantly evolving values is sometimes flaky depending on the browser you are using.  I remember Firefox and Safari both being a PITA when trying to do this 2 years ago.

Anyway, you might consider a completely different tact and read/write the value into a hidden form field whose value is simply emitted back by your master page.